# Create anonymous unix os_pipe in rust and read it from python

Tags: python-3.x, rust, pipe

I have a program that takes a fd to a pipe as argument. To simplify things I am simulating the python program as follows

`src/test.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os
import sys

fd = int(sys.argv[1])
print("fd:", fd)
r = os.fdopen(fd, 'r')
print("pipe content: ", r.read())
```

I am creating the pipe and passing the fd as follows

`src/main.rs`

```
use std::io::Write;
use std::os::unix::io::IntoRawFd;

fn main() {
    let (pipe_reader, mut pipe_writer) = os_pipe::pipe().unwrap();
    write!(pipe_writer, "write content").unwrap();
    let out = std::process::Command::new("./src/test.py")
        .arg(pipe_reader.into_raw_fd().to_string())
        .output()
        .unwrap();
    println!(
        "STDOUT: {}\nSTDERR: {}",
        String::from_utf8_lossy(&out.stdout),
        String::from_utf8_lossy(&out.stderr)
    );
}
```

There is a fd since "STDOUT: fd: 3" get's printed by python. However, python errors with "OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor"

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Found a similar problem which gives the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55540577/how-to-communicate-a-rust-and-a-ruby-process-using-a-unix-socket-pair